# Python: Using Pandas and Regex to Clean Phone Numbers with Country Code

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I'm attempting to use pandas to clean phone numbers so that it returns only the 10 digit phone number and removes the country code if it is present and any special characters.

Here's some sample code:

```
phone_series = pandas.Series(['+1(192) 167-4056', '123-345-4568', '1233455678', '(123) 123-1234'])
r1 = '[^0-9]+'
phone_series.str.replace(r1, '')
```

Returns

```
0    11921674056
1     1233454568
2     1233455678
3     1231231234
```

As you can see, this regex works well except for the country code. And unfortunately, this system I'm loading into cannot accept the country code. What I'm struggling with, is finding a regex that with strip the country code as well. All the regex's I've found will match the 10 digits I need, and in this case with using pandas, I need to not match them.

I could easily write a function and use .apply but I feel like there is likely a simple regex solution that I'm missing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not pure regex but could you use `phone_series.str.replace(r1, '')[-10:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think regex is necessary here, which is nice because regex is a pain in the buns.

To append your current solution:

```
phone_series = pandas.Series(['+1(192) 167-4056', '123-345-4568', '1233455678', '(123) 123-1234'])
r1 = '[^0-9]+'
phone_series.str.replace(r1, '')
phone_series = phone_series.apply(lambda x: x[-10:])
```

My lazier solution:

```
>>> phone_series = pd.Series(['+1(192) 167-4056', '123-345-4568', '1233455678', '(123) 123-1234'])
>>> p2 = phone_series.apply(lambda x: ''.join([i for i in x if str.isnumeric(i)])[-10:])
>>> p2
0    1921674056
1    1233454568
2    1233455678
3    1231231234
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking it and felt like I needed to use regex, but you're solution is much better.

Comment: @linkdkm No worries! Once you've been forced to use regex, you'll get better at finding ways to avoid it lol.